# What does applescript call a drop down menu?

Tags: applescript

This question concerns applescript syntax. What does applescript call a drop down menu? And what does applescript call an item on a  drop down menu?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/applescript-list-examples

Comment: Thanks, Twon-ha, but this doesn't seem relevant at all. I'm not trying to create an applescript application, just get a script to click on an item in a drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

This works via 'System Events'. Let's say you want to click 'open file...' from the 'file' menu.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    click menu item "Open file..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, NGAFD, but I meant a different kind of menu, for example any one of the four in the CDs and DVDs preference pane.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of that kind of menu and it's structure? It would make my help easier! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the author was looking for the term "pop up button" or "combo box".